# Are block-level elements allowed inside inline-level elements in HTML5?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

**For an example**

Is `<a href="#"><h1>Heading</h1></a>` valid in HTML5?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

yes what you've written is valid in HTML5, but it's not all inline elements, I think it's just `<a>` 's it applies to..

#### Reference: [“Block-level” links in HTML5](http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/)

Tip: if using this set the `<a>` to `display: block;` or there may be unintended visual styling results : [Source: Test Case](http://mattwilcox.net/sandbox/html5-block-anchor/test.html)

#### Update:

It is "disallowed" for other "block in inline" combinations where "default styles are likely to lead to confusion" - [explanation is here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#restrictions-on-content-models-and-on-attribute-values):

> #### Cases where the default styles are likely to lead to confusion
>
> Certain elements have default styles
> or behaviors that make certain
> combinations likely to lead to
> confusion. Where these have equivalent
> alternatives without this problem, the
> confusing combinations are disallowed.
>
> For example, div elements are rendered
> as block boxes, and span elements as
> inline boxes. Putting a block box in
> an inline box is unnecessarily
> confusing; since either nesting just
> div elements, or nesting just span
> elements, or nesting span elements
> inside div elements all serve the same
> purpose as **nesting a div element in
> a span element**, but only the latter
> involves a block box in an inline box,
> **the latter combination is disallowed.**