# Is it valid to put h2 tag in span tag?

Tags: seo, html

Is it valid to put h2 tag in span tag given that the span tag is displayed as block?
would it make difference for search engines (SEO) if i used div instead

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sample input:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head><title></title></head>
<body>
    <span style="display: block">
        <h2>A</h2>
    </span>
</body>
</html>
```

And results from [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input):

> Element **`h2` not allowed as child of element `span`** in this context.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't. Accordind to HTML 4.01/XHTML 1.0 dtd you can include only inline elements in span tag. It's the following one:

a, object, applet, img, map, iframe, br, span, bdo, tt, i, b, u, s, strike, big, small, font, basefont, sub, sup, em, strong, dfn, code, q, samp, kbd, var, cite, abbr, acronym, input, select, textarea, label, button, ins, del, script.

Can't quickly check HTML 5, but don't think it's different here.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML4, it is not valid to put any [block element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Block-level_elements) inside of any [inline element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Inline_elements).

This changes in HTML5, where it is valid to put [block-level elements inside of anchor tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061869/are-block-level-elements-allowed-inside-inline-level-elements-in-html5).