# Why CSS selectors on links are tricky with underline with hover?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Here are two examples based on this HTML.

```
<a href="#">
    <div class="foo">
        hello
        <span class="bar">world</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

In the first one, I make the link not underline on hover, then make a sub-portion of the link underline, and that works fine:

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover .bar {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3qPyX/1/

In the second, I now reverse the selectors so that the second word should be **un**-underlined. However, now something strange happens. **The entire link remains underlined even though the selectors seem like they should remove underline from the second word.** *<-- (this is the question. why does this happen?)*

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover .bar {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EAmwt/

Can someone explain what's going wrong in the second example? Inspecting with Chrome shows the `span.bar` has a computed style of `text-decoration:none`.

**Update:** a few answers explaining how to get around the problem, which is great except that's not really my question. What I want to know is *why* is this behavior different than, say, bold? For instance, if I try the 2nd example with bold, I get the expected results: http://jsfiddle.net/3qPyX/4/

Comment: you are applying the underline to the `a` so taking it off `.bar` will have no effect as you haven't applied anything to bar

Comment: Just so that more people don't come in here yelling about the `<div>` inside the `<a>`: see [this question's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061869/are-block-level-elements-allowed-inside-inline-level-elements-in-html5) and [this David Walsh blog post](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-elements-links).

Comment: don't know what donald's problem was, just came on and gave people grief when he was wrong

Comment: Downvote because the question is not clear at all

Comment: Everybody writes a lot a of over-complicated things, if you need to underline only the first word, than you put only that in an element, and make the styling: http://jsfiddle.net/3qPyX/7/ . If you want to change the underline from one word to another on hover, then two separate elements: http://jsfiddle.net/3qPyX/2/

Comment: This isn't a question about `:hover` selectors so much as it is one about text decorations. A similar question can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481318/css-text-decoration-property-cannot-be-overridden-by-child-element). And @Seer, I don't see what's unclear about it - it asks why `text-decoration: none` on child does not appear to affect parent's text decoration.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Explanation:

The problem is that some properties (like [text-decoration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration#Notes)) get drawn to the whole parent inline element, whereas others - like font styling (that get inherited) - get overriden by the children properties.

**Just for illustration:** simmilarly, if you set a background color to a parent element it will paint the background of the parent ... and you would have to set another color to a child to lay it over (default - transparent - will still show the parent style through), but if you set font-weight at a child it will apply to the text inside the child element and override the parent settings.

You can find more detailed stuff on the `text-decoration` property in the [CSS Level 2](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html) and [Level 3 Specifications](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text-decor-3/).

---

### A simple solution

**withot changing the markup**, you could just display `.bar` as `inline-block`.

Like so:

```
a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover .bar {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

And the inline-block *breaks out of the inline/text styling* of the parent anchor element =) And you can then style it independently:

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EAmwt/10)

Comment: I think "breaks the styling" is the key to understanding why this happens, but I still don't really get it, since I imagine underline to be something applied directly to the text, like bold in my example. What's the difference?

Comment: the font- styling properties work the way you expect, but text-decoration is not one of them ... and gets rendered to the whole element it is applied to, a sI explain in beggining of my answer. [READ MORE HERE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration#Notes)

Comment: I hope this answers your actual question ... and the solution suggested I merely add as it overcomes the problems with some intrinsic properties of the `text-decoration` selector ;-) It would make it a bit harder to answer if you also want to know *why* they decided to implement the selector in this specific manner.

Comment: @RobertMartin see Changes to CSS2.1 spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/changes.html#q475 „C.7.86  Section 16.3.1 Underlining, overlining, striking, and blinking: the 'text-decoration' property“ — Note that *text decorations* are *not propagated* to *floating and absolutely positioned descendants*, nor to the contents of atomic inline-level descendants such as ​_inline blocks_ and inline tables.

Answer (score 2):

When you do the `text-decoration` it is applied to the entire line at once. So the `a:hover .bar`  doesn't cause any effect, because the underline is not being applied in the `.bar` but on the `a`.

Here is the specification: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#lining-striking-props

Comment: Indeed. [This jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EAmwt/5/) shows the effect without the `a` element or the `:hover` behaviour.

Comment: If you would want to underline just the first part of the anchor you should make a separate span for that one: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EAmwt/6/). The parent will always draw the line behind the child.

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE! (As @Cam suggested) :

You need the add in separate elements the parts of your text: http://jsfiddle.net/3qPyX/5/

The CSS:

```
.foo, a:hover .bar, a {
    text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover .foo {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: Remove .bar text-decoration: to none. And you have the answer. Make sure to read the question thoroughly.

Comment: Hmm, but he would like the first word underlined on hover, and the second word underlined in normal state, no? @Robert Martin ?

Comment: No he wants it reversed. You got the answer just fix that and your golden. +1