# How to configure CKEditor to allow html block-level tags to be wrapped in an anchor tag

Tags: html, ckeditor

I would like to wrap a few block tags in a link ([valid in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061869/are-block-level-elements-allowed-inside-inline-level-elements-in-html5)):

```
<a href="http://example.com">
  <div>foo</div>
  <p>bar</p>
  <span>baz</span>
  <strong>zoom</strong>
</a>
```

But CKEditor rewrites the code such that the links are placed inside block tags and allowed to wrap inline tags as the above code is replaced with the following:

```
<div><a href="http://example.com">foo</a></div>
<p><a href="http://example.com">bar</a></p>
<a href="http://example.com"><span>baz</span> <strong>zoom</strong> </a>
```

How can I disable this behavior?

In the CKEditor config, I'm using [`config.allowedContent = true;`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-allowedContent) which disables the filtering of allowed tags.

We're also using [`config.autoParagraph = false;`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-autoParagraph) to not require root-level tags to be wrapped in a paragraph.

I've tried using [`config.extraAllowedContent = "a p; a div";`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-extraAllowedContent), but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: You could post-process the content; add a class for example to the ones you want to wrap and then force them afterwards. Or wrap all of them inside a DIV with some ID/class so you could convert them to a link.

Comment: CKEDITOR BUG: http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/7961 and http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9457

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment CKEditor (4.2) is xHTML/HTML4 editor only. There's no support support for HTML5 DTD (which is dynamic, BTW) and this is the root of your problem. I'm also afraid there's no workaround/config since different DTD means different parser, so CKEditor is not the right tool for you. Sorry.

You can find more information in [this ticket](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/9457).

Answer (score 10):

You can try doing something similar to this:

```
CKEDITOR.dtd.a.div = 1;
CKEDITOR.dtd.a.p = 1;
```

src:
http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/CKEditor-wont-allow-inside