# disable removing anchor tag outside div tag in ckeditor

Tags: html, ckeditor

I'm using ckeditor and after updating its changed position of anchor tags. How to resolve this problem?

```
<a href="print">
<div class="item-img-wrap">
<div class="item-img-overlay">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
</a>
```

After updating its changed to:

```
<div class="item-img-wrap"><a href="print"></a>

<div class="item-img-overlay">&nbsp;</div>
<a href="print"> </a></div>
```

How to resolve this problem in ckeditor?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091739/div-inside-anchor

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to configure CKEditor to allow html block-level tags to be wrapped in an anchor tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19825802/how-to-configure-ckeditor-to-allow-html-block-level-tags-to-be-wrapped-in-an-anc)