# Half selectable div when transformed with CSS

Tags: html, css, transform

When I transform a div with CSS transforms, the text and/or links in that div are only selectable in the left half of the div.

I've created a simple sample of the problem I have:

http://jsfiddle.net/mgA6z/

Does anyone have a solution to make the whole text/links clickable? The full link gets clickable whhen the rotateY is removed:

```
-webkit-transform: rotateY(30deg);
```

Comment: Not answering your question, but a block level element (`<p>`) cannot be within your anchor (`<a>`). Do it the other way around — `<p><a>text</a></p>`

Comment: @Daze - just for the record - in html5 block elements ARE allowed within anchors [Are block-level elements allowed inside inline-level elements in HTML5?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061869/are-block-level-elements-allowed-inside-inline-level-elements-in-html5)

Comment: @Danield I stand corrected. Thank you for the reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you remove

```
 -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

the link is fully clickable (and visually there's no difference in the demo w/wo this property set).

Example (for webkit): http://jsfiddle.net/yvngm/