# Nesting Div To Make Button Around Tel: Link?

Tags: html, css, nested, tel

I tried to nest a div before closing my  tag to make a button around a tap to call tel: link:

```
                                        <a href=”tel:+18888888888">
                                            <div>
                                                <table>
                                                    <tbody>
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <td rowspan="2"><img id="phone" src="/phoneimg.png" alt="xx"></td>
                                                            <td rowspan="2">Tap To Call NOW!&#9;888.888.8888</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </div>
                                        </a>
```

When I upload the html file to my host I get a 404 error when I tap the button.

When I remove the div, and the  closing tag is right behind the a href=”tel:+18888888888" tag (i.e. it has correct syntax without a div container before the closing tag) it works but is simply an undecorated link.

Any way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your CSS.

Comment: You can not include block elements into inline elements. Make links inside of <td> tag

Answer (score 1):

As dfionov correctly stated, you cannot include block elements inside inline elements. Anchors (`<a>`) are  however an exception to the rule in HTML5, as [explained in another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061869/are-block-level-elements-allowed-inside-inline-level-elements-in-html5#6062035).

I would like to also mention that for your use-case, tables should be avoided. They are for displaying tabular data not aligning an image.

There are a number of ways to do this with CSS, I would probably suggest using [`inline-block`](http://chrisnager.com/simple-vertical-centering-with-css/) because it works on all modern browsers and is easier to understand than many of the alternatives.

```
<a href="tel:+18888888888">
    <img id="phone" src="/phoneimg.png" alt="xx">
    <span>Tap To Call NOW!&#9;888.888.8888</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Corrected code:

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td rowspan="2"><a href="tel:+18888888888"><img id="phone" src="/phoneimg.png" alt="xx"></a></td>
                <td rowspan="2"><a href="tel:+18888888888">Tap To Call NOW!&#9;888.888.8888</a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```