# Hyperlink not working on next line

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I can only get hyperlink working on the first line. When a line break is encountered the further hyperlink is not working it is only plain text!

The red box around the black text is the working hyperlink and green is not working as there is a link break.

[image: Output]

HTML:

```
<div class='data_block'>
    <img src='data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode( $row['ar_image'] )."' class='data_image'/>
     <div class='data_title'>
     <a href='article.php?no=".$row['ar_id']."'><p>"

19 hours ago by Sachin Bhandary Alarming Video From Manipur Shows Armed Forces"</p></a>
     </div>
     <div class='data_desc'>
    <p>".$row['ar_desc']."</p>
  </div>
</div>";
```

CSS:

```
.data_title a
{
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  font-weight: 600;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: right;
  margin-top:-25%;
  width:450px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left:auto;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:#2E84C2;
}
.data_title:hover a
{
    color: #272727;
}
```

Comment: Please post the rendered HTML, not the PHP or whatever server-side language that is.

Comment: Btw, you should use `<p><a ...>...</a></p>`, not nest `<p>` inside of `<a>`. Block elements should not be contained in inline elements

Comment: @Mifeet - it's valid in HTML5

Comment: I tried this jsfiddle and it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/pinturic/v3cm8rnc/ . If you have another non-working jsfiddle please share it.

Comment: @j08691 Ah, it's valid [for `<a>`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6062035/2032064) elements, good to know (although apparently not for all elements)

Comment: @pinturic I don't think jsfiddle can interpret the php code that is obviously included in the example.

Comment: @j08691 post edited.

Comment: The code you've now posted doesn't reproduce the behavior you described. Please update your question to include the code that will allow us to see the issue.

Comment: Yaa removing <p> worked! Sorry I did not had any idea about such stuff! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though it may be considere valid, it's not a good idea to nest the `<p>` tag inside an anchor tag. Try formatting your HTML like this:

```
<p>
    <a href='article.php?no=".$row['ar_id']."'>
        "19 hours ago by Sachin Bhandary Alarming Video From Manipur Shows Armed Forces"
    </a>
</p>
```

Comment: Why the down vote? It's a valid attempt to solve the problem

Comment: Well I didnt down vote! maybe someone else! I will mark it as answer