# How do I set the size of a bootstrap panel?

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, panel

So I am making a webpage using panels. The idea is to fetch rows from database and display it on panels. I set the width of the panel-primary to 15% and visually it resized the panel to 15%. I want to make the panel clickable so I added an (<'a'>) surrounding the panel to my surprise that even though the panel is visually 15% in size, it still takes the whole horizontal space. Notice the cursor is a hand

[image]

I attach my code for this part:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pembelitkataku";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
?>
<a href="">
    <div class="panel panel-primary" style="width: 15%">
        <div class="panel-heading"><?php echo $row['text']; ?></div>
        <div class="panel-body"><?php echo "<img src = 'images/".$row['image']."' width=\"100\">"?></div>
    </div>
</a>
<?php
}
?>
```

My question is, how do I visually and physically change the panel size to 15% so that I can put multiple panels side by side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchors  are inline elements, not block level. you should put your anchors inside the panel div, not wrapping it.

Comment: Actually, the OP's code is perfectly valid with the `<a>` tag wrapping the `<div>` like that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061869/are-block-level-elements-allowed-inside-inline-level-elements-in-html5

Comment: Not if he wants it to be a block level element. The a tag wrapping changes the div to an inline element - thus causing the issue. Syntactically, it is fine to do that, so long as you don't want your div to be a block element.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap panels will fit just fine inside [Bootstrap's columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid).

Try wrapping the full set of `<a>` tags in a `<div class="container">` and `<div class="row">`, then give each `<a>` tag a column class like `col-md-6` (two 50% width columns at larger screen sizes, switching to a single full-width column at smaller screen sizes).

Also, avoid using the hardcoded 15% width. Use the column classes to define the width, since Bootstrap's grid system is responsive by default.

Full example:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM pembelitkataku";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
while($row = $result->fetch_array())
{
?>
<a href="" class="col-md-2">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading"><?php echo $row['text']; ?></div>
        <div class="panel-body"><?php echo "<img src = 'images/".$row['image']."' width=\"100\">"?></div>
    </div>
</a>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
</div>
```

### UPDATE

To answer your specific question about 15% widths, try using the `col-md-2` class on all the `<a>` tags. This actually ends up being `16.66666667%`, but it will be visually similar to the 15% you wanted originally, while still letting you take advantage of Bootstrap's grid system so you can put multiple panels side by side. I updated my example to reflect this.