# Notification bar not dismissing on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Trying to create a privacy policy notification bar at the footer of a page and only showing for new visitors. Looking to dismiss the notification on click of acceptance. Right now the bar is showing up fixed at the bottom of page but I can't seem to get the notification bar to dismiss on click.

```
<span class="banner tracking-banner p-t-1">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-10 text-left m-b-1">
    This website uses cookies and other 3rd party services to customize and provide you a more personalized experience. To find out more, see our <a href="/privacy/">Privacy Policy</a>.
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 m-b-1">
    <button class="dismiss btn btn-sm btn-block btn-invert">Accept</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</span>
```

JS

```
$(".banner").fadeIn("slow").append(".container");
$(".dismiss").click(function(){
   $(".banner").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: [It's not good practice to put block elements (`div`) inside inline elements (`span`)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061869/are-block-level-elements-allowed-inside-inline-level-elements-in-html5).

Comment: are you calling your code inside document ready function or not ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wrap your code inside document ready function

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".banner").fadeIn("slow").append(".container");
$(".dismiss").click(function(){
   $(".banner").fadeOut("slow");
});
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span class="banner tracking-banner p-t-1">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-10 text-left m-b-1">
    This website uses cookies and other 3rd party services to customize and provide you a more personalized experience. To find out more, see our <a href="/privacy/">Privacy Policy</a>.
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 m-b-1">
    <button class="dismiss btn btn-sm btn-block btn-invert">Accept</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</span>
```

Comment: I've wrapped the code inside a document ready function as mentioned but it's not dismissing. Here is a link - http://dev.childcaresuccesssummit.com

Comment: run the code snippet above it is working as you expect , you should verify in your code that there arent any more buttons with the same class `.dismiss`.

Comment: Looks like based on your site, you are including jquery AFTER the script. jquery needs to exist before you start to use it.

Comment: Great! Thanks, @MuhammadOmerAslam. I was calling on my jquery after the script. Relocated it into my header and all is working now. Is there a way to simply add to the query so that it is only showing up for unique or new visitors and not the same visitor every time?

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyRivas. I relocated it into the header as mentioned

Comment: Looks like it is showing up on every page and not just on initial landing. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 0):

Change your span to div? make your fadeOut working.

```
<div class="banner tracking-banner p-t-1">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-10 text-left m-b-1">
    This website uses cookies and other 3rd party services to customize and provide you a more personalized experience. To find out more, see our <a href="/privacy/">Privacy Policy</a>.</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2 m-b-1">
    <button class="dismiss btn btn-sm btn-block btn-invert">Accept</button>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: this has nothing to do with span